# Insert data from Python to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to insert some data from a python dataframe, already created in Jupyter Notebook, to SQL Server Management Studio 18

The code I have written both in Python and the SQL server is presented below

**PANDAS DATAFRAME**

(this is a typical row of my dataframe)

Movie Title IMDB Rating Actors  Director    Plot Summary    Plot Keywords   Genres

Avatar  7.8 [Sam-Worthington, Zoe-Saldana, Sigourney-Weave] James-Cameron   A paraplegic Marine dispatched to the moon Pan  [avatar, future, marine, native, paraplegic] [Action, Adventure, Fantasy]

[Python Dataframe Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQpGg.png)

**SQL**

```
USE Movies_Dataset;
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data_table;
GO
CREATE TABLE data_table
(
 [MovieID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,[Movie_Title] VARCHAR(MAX)
,[IMDB_Rating] VARCHAR(MAX)
,[Actors] VARCHAR(MAX)
,[Direcor] VARCHAR(MAX)
,[Plot_Summary] VARCHAR(MAX)
,[Plot_Keywords] VARCHAR(MAX)
,[Genres] VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

**PYTHON**

```
import pyodbc

connStr = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                         "SERVER=LAPTOP-IFTEP7AL;"
                         "DATABASE=Movies_Dataset;"
                         "Trusted_Connection=yes")

cursor = connStr.cursor()

for index, row in final_dataset.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.data_table(
    [Movie_Title], 
    [IMDB_Rating], 
    [Actors], 
    [Director], 
    [Plot_Summary], 
    [Plot_Keywords],
    [Genres]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", 
    row['Movie Title'],row['IMDB 
Rating'],row['Actors'],row['Director'],row['Plot Summary'],row['Plot 
Keywords'],row['Genres']) 

connStr.commit()

cursor.close()

connStr.close()
```

Although my code seems to be fine, does not work. And I suspect this is because I try to insert a list (like actors or genres) instead of varchars.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

[The error I get (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmcgG.png)

Also I used sqlalchemy with the following python code:

```
import pyodbc

import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import urllib

quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 
11.0};SERVER=LAPTOP-IFTEP7AL;DATABASE=Movies_Dataset")

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

final_dataset.to_sql('data_table', schema='dbo', con = engine)

result = engine.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[data_table]')

result.fetchall()
```

[the error from sqlalchemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQDs.png)

Comment: Have a look into creating an 'engine' object from sqlalchemy and pass this into the 'con' argument of DataFrame.to_sql().  This way you can basically just INSERT your whole DataFrame in a single call.

Comment: The database design seems to lack normalization here at every turn. Are you storing delimited lists of data? Also you really don't need varchar(max) for most of this. A more reasonable varchar size exists for most of this stuff (and all of it with proper normalization).

Comment: @S3DEV I made an edit with the sqlalchemy code

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah I try to store list like in the column "Actors". I have 3 actors ['actor 1', 'actor 2', 'actor 3']....About the normalization you mentioned. I don't think that is a problem in my case since I want to pass the dataframe as it is!

Comment: With your recent changes you have links to two different images of error messages. Which one are you struggling with.

Comment: So you pass the entire dataframe back and forth and never have to query it? Storing delimited lists like that is not a good idea. It violates 1NF.

Comment: @SeanLange both errors are from two different approaches. The first approach uses pyodbc, the second uses sqlalchemy. Both ways lead to an error. So If I solve at least one will be perfect. My goal is only one: pass a dataframe to sql

Comment: Well the second one is pretty clear. The user information you are passing to open the sql connection is invalid.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah I thought so, the fact that I try to pass a list was not a good idea

Comment: @SeanLange Managed to overpass the error

Comment: OK. Well the login failed. What user is actually trying to connect? You can find that with extended events or go old school with sql profiler. And does that user have permission to connect? Do they have the permission needed in your database?

Comment: @SeanLange overpassed the connection error...now I have this DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah I try this from last night...it's not something important...I may skip it for the moment. THank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use pyodbc normally use procedures..

```
import pyodbc

connStr = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                         "SERVER=LAPTOP-IFTEP7AL;"
                         "DATABASE=Movies_Dataset;"
                         "Trusted_Connection=yes")

cursor = connStr.cursor()

sqlExecSP="""\
                        EXEC [dbo].[InsertInMyTable] @Movie_Title = ? ,@IMDB_Rating = ? ,@Actors = ? ,@Director = ?;
          """   

for index, row in final_dataset.iterrows():

    params = (row['Movie Title'],row['IMDBRating'],row['Actors'],row['Director'])
    cursor.execute(sqlExecSP, params)

connStr.commit()

cursor.close()

connStr.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Gioviani, for the reply! I will test your code later today and I will inform you about the results. Have a good day! :)